# Display numbers with padding and a fixed number of digits in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

I'd like to display numbers using a padding (if necessary) and a fixed number of digits. For instance, given the following numbers:

```
48.3
0.3485
5.2
```

Display them like this:

```
48.30
00.35
05.20
```

I'm trying combinations of std::fixed, std::fill, std::setw, and std::setprecision, but I can't seem to get what I'm looking for. Would love some guidance!

NOTE: The 0-padding isn't really critical, but I'd still like the numbers to be aligned such that the decimal point is in the same column.

Comment: http://arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setfill('0');
    cout << setw(5) << 48.3 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 0.3485 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 5.2 << endl;
}
```

Writing code like this makes me yearn for `printf` however.

Comment: This breaks if setprecision goes too high. Does setw have to be greater than setprecision + 3 or something?

Comment: If you want two leading digits and a decimal point then yes, setw must be >= setprecision + 3.

Comment: As an additional note, I think a big problem was that I was (earlier in the line) setting the alignment with `std::left`. That also messes up this solution, so I had to make sure to set it back to `std::right` for this to work.

Comment: While it does make me miss `printf` I like the C++ way because I can apply this to a `stringstream` and get the output as `string`